# How do I avoid an EX Hooligan Combination?

Tags: ultra-street-fighter-iv

I recently picked up USF4 and jumped into ranked online to immerse myself in a trial by fire method of learning how to play. I just ran into a Cammy user who liked to use the EX version of the attack where she curls up into a ball and jumps across the screen, then grabs you.

She really liked that move, and it hit me every single time she used it. I tried blocking and jumping, but in either case she had no problem just grabbing me and getting free damage. How do you avoid this attack?

Comment: normaly you should be abel to jump away from that (timing is the key of this game) :D . To be shure jump backwords than you should be out of range and on a diffrent altitude as her.

Comment: @GEnGEr She always did it at full screen. Maybe that's why jumping away didn't work?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U7SUnTdD4E at like 1:14 you can see a simple dodge for the Ex Holligan if its realy the thing you mean

Answer (score 1):

EX Hooligan Combination is a very, very risky move to use, as it makes Cammy extremely punishable.  This isn't very easy to spam because it consumes meter (1 bar), and you obviously need a Super meter with some bars to use it.

To punish it, there are several options. One, is crouch.  If you crouch, the EX Hooligan will simply jump over your character on the other side, not even hitting you.  Another option similar to crouching is to forward dash when Cammy begins the inital jump.  This will actually ruin the trajectory and cause her to land behind you. However, DO NOT backdash.  Cammy will grab you even if you backdash, so forward dash to avoid the throw.

Another very easy way to punish is to spam cr.lp (crouching, light punch).   Most characters can easily combo from cr.lp into other moves.

If your character has anti-airs, use them.  During Hooligan Throw, Cammy is considered airborne, so use anti-air moves, including DPs (shoryuken), abel's FS (falling sky), El Fuerte's Guacamole, etc.

One last thing to note. EX Hooligan should be typically used to punish fireballs. This means if you face a player who repeatedly spams the move, don't try to Hadouken them out of it or fireball constantly, or risk getting punished.

Comment: i voted you down because you were so negative to the other answerer.

Comment: That's not what downvotes are for.  Retaliation is never a valid use.  You can flag his comments for moderation instead.

Answer (score -1):

Caveat: I don't play Street Fighter.

Judging from a bit of Googling, the move seems to be the Hooligan Throw:

"The Hooligan Throw will only grab characters who are standing or jumping; not crouching. Because of this, most players will just duck under your Hooligan Spin and wait.

[...]

EX Version: The EX Hooligan Combination travels through the air MUCH faster than the regular version. It also auto-tracks the opponent and locks onto their position. These two properties make it difficult to react to, but you'll still want to be careful because the Throw and Slide properties are the same."
- http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2009/jan/18/cammy-street-fighter-4-character-guide/

Comment: If you don't play Street Fighter, why would you bother answering the question? In this case, you have zero experience playing the game, and I'd expect the answerer to have at least basic knowledge of Cammy if he were going to answer it

Comment: WTF, according to your answer, my answer was right anyway. You're surprisingly negative for someone with such a large reputation score.

Comment: Only for the first part.  You clearly don't address other options that can be used. A good answer should deeply  analyze the problem, not provide one small tip.

Comment: And even so, you clearly don't mention how to counter an EX Hooligan, which is something that I don't see in your paragraph

Comment: According to the description, the EX version can be countered by crouching, same as to counter non-EX. "The Throw and Slide properties are the same." "To have at least basic knowledge of" a key character in the question is not mandatory criteria for answering a question, and by a certain standard, it could be said that I "have at least basic knowledge".

Comment: Maybe you should have at least addressed that in your answer, not just copied and pasted from Ehubs?   "And since the EX move has the same properties as the normal version, as listed above, crouching will have the same effect". Something like that.  And even so, that's just one option out of many others that should have been addressed.

Comment: I thought that I did address that. Sorry that I thought it wouldn't have been missed. Sorry that I prefer the authority of citation over my own lack of knowledge. Sorry that I didn't find more in my research. You're right; I shouldn't have posted at all. My answer probably ruined their past 23 days.

Comment: You can never assume that someone who asks a question will automatically figure out what you're trying to say. Since Strix was asking for how to counter an EX Hooligan, you could have put a small tidbit at the bottom of the paragraph to let him know, rather than assume he'd figure it out.